# Winform control inside HTML page

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, winforms

We are trying to develop a web enabled application to read serial port data (weigh bridge data). We developed a winform control to real the serial/com port.
We added the control inside an html file and published it.

For testing we created a simple label in winform and tried to access it via javascript.

Winform with label

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    namespace WindowsFormsControlLibrary1
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public partial class UserControl1: UserControl
        {
            public UserControl1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            public void SendMessage(string msg)
            {
                _lblMessage.Text = msg;
            }
        }
    }
```

Javascript function inside HTML

```
    function SendMessageToWinControl()
        {
         var winCtrl = document.getElementById("MyWinControl");                   
         winCtrl.SendMessage("Message sent from the HTML page!!");
        }
```

Declared the object uisng the classid

```
    classid="http:WindowsFormsControlLibrary1.dll#WindowsFormsControlLibrary1.UserControl1"
```

We provided everyone access to the folder. Added the Allow Extension from path in ISAPI.
But what we get is the following screen,

[image]

Can someone please help? We are using .net 4.0
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're creating a horrendous aberration. winforms is NOT Web and does not belong in a Web Application. You will regret this decision, just like Prof. Victor Frankenstein after bringing his monster to life.

Comment: If you need a Web Application, I strongly suggest you use standard Web Technologies (HTML / CSS / JavaScript). If you need to create a Windows Desktop application, use WPF. If you need to create a Windows 8 "Metro Style" application, use WinRT XAML. winforms is completely useless at this point.

Comment: We want Web Technologies. We are trying everything possible. But something somewhere goes wrong.